# How to concat or pass this variable when isset is called?

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album_id=$album['id']')
```

Now I am sure all of you can see the error here I am trying to check if this link is clicked

```
<a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=album_id=<?php echo $album['id'];?>">
```

Now this link works and displays as it should in the url but I can not figure out how to pass $album['id'] to the if statements isset?

EDIT

ok i did this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=album_id&action_id=<?php echo $album['id'];?>">
```

and

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'album_id' && $_GET['action_id'] == $album['id'])
```

and returned undefined variable in the if statement says album is undefined variable

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

Here is my entire php file:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
include 'init.image.php';
protect_page();
 include 'includes/overall/overall_header.php';


if(isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false){
$username       = $_GET['username'];


if(user_exists($username) === true){
$user_id        = user_id_from_username($username);
$profile_data   = user_data($user_id, 'first_name','last_name','email', 'username');
?>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?>'s Yor Page</h1>

<div id="navWrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="uploads/profile/blank_profile.gif" width="150" height="150" id="blank_profile"></a>
        </li>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=albums">Albums</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=music">Music</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='albums'){

$albums = get_profile_albums($user_id);

if(empty($albums)){
echo 'No Albums';
}else{
foreach($albums as $album){
if (empty($album['image'])) {

    $album['image'] = 'uploads/profile/blank_profile.gif';
}

?>
 <p><?php echo $album['name'],' (', $album['count'], ')'?> <br />
  <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username']; ?>?action=album&album_id=<?php echo $album['id']; ?>">
    <img src="uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $album['id'];?>/<?php echo $album['image'];?>" />
  </a><br />
  <?php echo $album['description'];?>...<br />
  </p>
<?php



}


}


}
else if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album' && isset($_GET['album_id'])){
echo 'albums';
}







if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='music'){
echo'<h1>Music</h1>';
}

}else{
    echo 'Sorry, that user doesn\'t exist';
}
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include 'includes/overall/overall_footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: can you actually do that? put parameters in url like `action=album_id=1`?

Comment: yes it returns the album id of whatever album is clicked on using that link.

Comment: feel kinda weird, maybe I'm still kinda new to php, but i would recommend another way

Comment: I know it looks like spaghetti code and I am new too taking on prob a lil more than I can handle but I am determined and if I knew an alternative I would take it.

Comment: can you also put the output of the url rewrite, I'm not too good with the rewrite syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a destination, where's the php file you try to access? You started with `username`. Check here `href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?`

Try separate the action and the id, it's probably just me, I found it kinda weird to put it like `action=album=1`

you can try like this

```
$_GET['action'] == 'album' && $_GET['action_id'] == $album['id']
```

so the url would be looking like

```
?action=album&action_id=1
```

Comment: I tried that and got an error see my question i edited it to show you

Comment: Yes that works the url works and returns the username and the album id correctly but I can not get $album['id'] for some reason, I have done this already to get to this user profile page this code is on and now I am trying to link that users pics to users profile page with the link and GET function.

Comment: if `$album['id']` can't print out, then you probably wanna check if you set it correctly.

Comment: I did I can echo it outisde the if statement and it does echo correctly.

Comment: I added my htaccess file is there something in there that has to be done?

Comment: I don't think it's .htaccess issue. did you try make a new variable like this `$test_var = 'album_id=' . $album['id'];` and put `$_GET['action'] == $test_var` instead? Just to test it out

Comment: Yes still undefined variable.

Comment: I konw I know I am stumped I have done this before and when I click on the link it shows lr/aaron?action=album&id=19    aaron is the correct username of the profile being viewed and album id of 19 is the correct album being passed by $album['id'].

Comment: can i swith this to chat just not to make comments too long?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14777/discussion-between-user1301840-and-aaron-warnke)

Answer (score 1):

the proper way would be to have the url properly encoded:

```
<a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=<?php echo urlencode('album_id='.$album['id']); ?>">
```

and then decode it

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && urldecode($_GET['action'])=='album_id='.$album['id'])
```

Comment: It throws an error says undefined variable album in the if statement

Comment: so what exactly do you want the action equal to in the if statement? If `$album` isn't defined at the point where you're doing the if check then you cannot use it for testing `$_GET['action']`s value...

Comment: IT is defined I can echo it out, outside the if statement.

Comment: If I echo $album['id']; outside the if statement it returns that users correct album id for me.

Comment: I added my htaccess file to the question if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Dreen answered to your question, but I would separate the action parameter to something like action and id:

```
<a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=album&id=<?php echo $album['id'];?>">
```

and check

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album' && isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']==$album['id'])
```

Comment: No it's the same error undefined variable album in the if statement, it's like the compiler is not recognizing the ['id'] on the end of the variable because the error does not mention it at all just album.

Comment: I guess that's the error from `$album['id']`. Do you actually set the value?

Comment: Yes I can echo it out outside of the if statement and it echos correctly. Actually in the url it displays it as well just like the link in my question is suppose to work.